# Joomla query - create link to post

Tags: php, joomla

Im using the following joomla query which shows the id and the title of the article. Now i need to show the link the post for every article inside this query but i dont know how.

In this example i use the placeholder "HERE GET URL" to show where the link should be placed.

```
<?php 
    $catId = 43;
    $query = "SELECT * FROM #__content WHERE catid ='" . $catId . "'";
    $db = JFactory::getDBO();
    $db->setQuery($query); 
    $articles = $db->loadObjectList(); 

    foreach ($articles as $article) {
        echo 'ID: ' . $article->id;
        echo '<br />';
        echo 'Name: ' . $article->title;
        echo '<br /><br />';
        echo '<a href="' . $article->HERE GET URL; . '">To Article</a>';
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to create article link from article ID.

```
JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id='.$article->id);
```

Comment: This solutions works perfect and is exactly what i need.

Comment: ContentHelperRoute is here to help making link to articles. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The best is to use ContentHelperRoute :

```
JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($id, $catid, $language));
```

$catid and $language can be omitted.